# How can I suppress Javac warning about preview features?

Tags: java, javac, java-13

I'm using Java 13 (*13.0.1.hs-adpt*) and I enabled the preview language features (mainly because of text blocks).

My code is properly annotated with `@SuppressWarnings("preview")` wherever relevant, but I still get

```
Note: Some input files use preview language features.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:preview for details.
```

whenever I compile.

I understand that that's not the compiler printing warnings (in fact, `-Xlint:-preview` doesn't change anything).

Is there a way to suppress these messages?

Comment: This warning can’t be disabled.

Comment: @zforgo I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment. Cite some documentation if possible

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot suppress the "use of preview features" warning. From [JEP 12: Preview Language and VM Features](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12):

> Whether preview language features are enabled or disabled, `javac` in JDK `$N` prints a message if it detects the use of a preview language feature of Java SE `$N` in source code. This message cannot be turned off by using `@SuppressWarnings` in source code, because developers must be unfailingly aware of their reliance on the Java SE `$N` version of a preview language feature; the feature may change subtly in Java SE `$N+1`. The message looks like this:
>
> ```
> Note: Some input files use a preview language feature.
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:preview for details.
> ```

It also mentions the use of `@SuppressWarnings("preview")` in the section labeled *Relationship to Java SE APIs*:

> 4. When compiling with preview features *enabled*, any source code reference to an essential API element associated with a preview feature must generate a warning. This warning is suppressible with `@SuppressWarnings("preview")`, unlike the warning given by javac when it detects the use of a preview language feature in source code; the use of an essential API element is considered slightly less severe (and hence suppressible) than the use of a preview language feature.

Where the meaning of "essential API" is explained previously in the same section:

> 1. *Essential*. The API exists because code cannot enjoy the preview feature without it. Such an API lives in `java.*` and the JLS will refer to it in normative text. For example, [the enhanced-for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) relies on `java.lang.Iterable`, and [the try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) relies on `java.lang.AutoCloseable`.

Your warning is not from the use of "essential API" but from the use of the preview feature itself, which means `@SuppressWarnings("preview")` is not applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 6):

This article [Evolving Java With ––enable–preview aka Preview Language Features](https://blog.codefx.org/java/enable-preview-language-features/) describes what is the main purpose why this warning cannot be disabled.

> Imagine everybody started experimenting with preview features (or
>   incubator modules, for that matter) and then spreading that code and
>   the artifacts around. When a feature changes, they become outdated
>   after just a few months and maintaining such dependencies would become
>   a nightmare. Don’t worry, though, there are a number of safeguards
>   preventing exactly that. Well, from happening accidentally at least.

[This additional link](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-suppress_warnings.htm&cp=1_4_1_4) shows what `@SuppressWarning` values are supported by the latest Eclipse IDE

#### UPDATE

Here is the OpenJDK's source code which is proves this warning is always enabled.
[full source of Preview class](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/code/Preview.java)

```java
public class Preview {

    /** flag: are preview features enabled */
    private final boolean enabled;

    /** the diag handler to manage preview feature usage diagnostics */
    private final MandatoryWarningHandler previewHandler;

    /** test flag: should all features be considered as preview features? */
    private final boolean forcePreview;

    /** a mapping from classfile numbers to Java SE versions */
    private final Map<Integer, Source> majorVersionToSource;


    private final Lint lint;
    private final Log log;

    private static final Context.Key<Preview> previewKey = new Context.Key<>();

    public static Preview instance(Context context) {
        Preview instance = context.get(previewKey);
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Preview(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    Preview(Context context) {
        context.put(previewKey, this);
        Options options = Options.instance(context);
        enabled = options.isSet(PREVIEW);
        log = Log.instance(context);
        lint = Lint.instance(context);
        this.previewHandler =
                new MandatoryWarningHandler(log, lint.isEnabled(LintCategory.PREVIEW), true, "preview", LintCategory.PREVIEW);
        forcePreview = options.isSet("forcePreview");
        majorVersionToSource = initMajorVersionToSourceMap();
    }
...
}
```

The mandatoriness was hardcoded at the 3rd parameter (`enforceMandatory`) of `MandatoryWarningHandler`'s.

[Full source of MandatoryWarningHandler](https://github.com/kohsuke/javap/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/javac/util/MandatoryWarningHandler.java)

```java
public class MandatoryWarningHandler {
...
    /**
     * Create a handler for mandatory warnings.
     * @param log     The log on which to generate any diagnostics
     * @param verbose Specify whether or not detailed messages about
     *                individual instances should be given, or whether an aggregate
     *                message should be generated at the end of the compilation.
     *                Typically set via  -Xlint:option.
     * @param enforceMandatory
     *                True if mandatory warnings and notes are being enforced.
     * @param prefix  A common prefix for the set of message keys for
     *                the messages that may be generated.
     * @param lc      An associated lint category for the warnings, or null if none.
     */
    public MandatoryWarningHandler(Log log, boolean verbose,
                                   boolean enforceMandatory, String prefix,
                                   LintCategory lc) {
        this.log = log;
        this.verbose = verbose;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.enforceMandatory = enforceMandatory;
        this.lintCategory = lc;
    }
...
}
```